# Formatting till Hour only in a Date Time Variable

Tags: r, datetime, extract

I have a DateTime variable, with an example value as 2017-03-06-09.35.44.660000

I would like to have these values till Hours only: 2017-03-06-09

How do I do this in R?

Comment: try `strftime('2017-03-06-09.35.44.660000',format = '%Y-%m-%d-%H')`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
time <- "2017-03-06-09.35.44.660000"
time2 <- ymd_hms(time)
time3 <- ymd_h(paste0(year(time2), "-", month(time2), "-", day(time2), "-", hour(time2)))
time3
# "2017-03-06 09:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: What does UTC mean?